# Rewrite URLs amigables en servicio de acortamiento de urls sin base de datos

Tags: php, .htaccess

Estoy muy confudido así que decidí adquirir soporte de la comunidad de Stack Overflow.

Tengo un servicio de acortamiento de URLs sin base de datos que almacena las URLs en el directorio /urls y se pueden acceder como sitio.com/url, sin tener que escribir sitio.com/urls/url.php y eliminando la extensión de archivo PHP. Lo que significa que cuando se escribe sitio.com/url, se está haciendo un rewrite de sitio.com/index.php?url=$1, lo que en mi código PHP incluye el archivo, revisando primero si existe o no.

Eso ya está listo y funcional. Utilizo el siguiente código en mi .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ index.php?url=$1.php
```

Y también utilizo el siguiente código PHP en el archivo index.php para que se pueda llevar a cabo el rewrite de manera correcta:

```
if($_GET['url']){
$requestedshortenedurl = $_GET['url'];
$urlpath = "urls/$requestedshortenedurl";
if (file_exists($urlpath))
{
    echo "";     
}
else
{
    header("Location: sitio.com?error=4");
    exit;
}

include ("urls/$requestedshortenedurl");
exit;
} else {
    echo "";
}
```

Ahora estaba buscando como hacer que sitio.com?stats=url&visits y sitio.com?stats=url&visitors se puedan escribir como sitio.com/stats/url/visits y sitio.com/stats/url/visitors.

Estoy utilizando el siguiente código en mi .htaccess el cual no está funcionando:

```
# Rewrite for shortened URLs visits
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^stats/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?stats=$1.txt&visits [L]

# Rewrite for shortened URLs visitors
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^stats/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?stats=$1.txt&visitors [L]
```

Y estoy utilizando el siguiente código en mi archivo index.php:

```
// Define variable stats
$stats = $_GET['stats'];
// Switch stats cases (visits or visitors)
if($_GET['stats'])
switch($_GET['stats']) {
            case 'visits' :
                if (file_exists($statsvisits))
{
    include ("stats/$statsvisits");     
}
else
{
    header("Location: sitio.com?error=4");
    exit;
}
                break;
            case 'visitors' :
                if (file_exists($statsvisitors))
{
    include ("stats/$statsvisitors");     
}
else
{
    header("Location: sitio.com?error=4");
    exit;
}
                break;
    default :
        header("Location: sitio.com?error=4");
        break;
}
```

Lo cual no está funcionando y me lleva a sitio.com?error=4 (la página de error 404).

El archivo en el que estoy testeando es stpe-visits.txt, el cual se encuentra en sitio.com/stats/stpe-visits.txt. Al escribir sitio.com/urls/stpe-visits, no funciona.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Añade estas reglas al `.htaccess`

```
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^$ index.php?/ [QSA,L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule (.*) index.php?stats=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Siendo `stats` el string que vas a recibir por la `URL`